# How to find all elements with a specified backgroundimage

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

i am searching for a way to select all objects, with a specified backgroundImage.
I have already tried things like:

```
$.each($('*'), function(){
  if ($(this).css('backgroundImage')){
    console.info("backroundimage");
  }else {
    console.info("no backgroundimage");
  }
});
```

Some better ideas?

Comment: this is very extensive you can improve it by only selecting the objects/elements that can possibly have the bg like `$.each($('div'), function(){` also `$(this).css('backgroundImage')` will return the bg of current element to comapare it you can try `if($(this).css('backgroundImage')=='someBGimage')`

Comment: testing for 'none' would be a solution:

    $.each($('*'), function(){
      if($(this).css('backgroundImage') != 'none'){
      console.info($(this).css('backgroundImage'));
      }
    });

Comment: very right, i missed that one ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Filters?](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('*').filter(function() {
     return $(this).css('background-image') == 'image.png';
});
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning anything that selects '*' is an expensive selector (slow) if used on a big page - use carefully. Also, @Steve's answer below accounts for the fact that this property returns "url('....')" instead of simply the image filename as implied here.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
var elementsWithBG = $('.YourSelector').filter(function(){
    return this.style.backgroundImage != ''
});
```

Of course not all elements will have a background such as span, links, etc. Using `*` is expensive, you can separate needed elements with a comma instead of `'.YourSelector'` eg:

```
$('div, p, etc')
```

Comment: Caveat: While this will get all elements you explicitly set like tag.style.backgroundImage..., it will not get any elements who inherited a background-image from a CSS rule. @BobTodd's answer will get both, because jQuery's implementation of the .css() getter uses currentStyle/getComputedStyle. http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much achieved the crux of it there.

To expand upon what you have already:

```
$('*').each(function(){

    var bgImgStr = $(this).css('backgroundImage'),
        regEx = /\"|\'|\)/g,
        bgImgName = bgImgStr.split('/').pop().replace(regEx,'');

    if(bgImgName === 'whatever.jpg'){

        // do something

    }

});
```

Incedentally, the regEx part srtips everything but the filename (if one exists). The reason for this addition is because - depending on the browser - you may find yourself with something like:

```
url('../images/myImg.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sort of on the right track:

```
var url = $(this).css("background-image");
if (url == theExpectedImageUrl) {
  //found image
});
```

But as noted in comments, doing this for *all* elements perhaps isn't the way to go!